# ajax calling php loop with form not working on first loop only

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a page called events.php that lists past and upcoming events, using ajax to call on pastevents.php and upcomingevents.php, which both have forms that collect users' opinions on past events and whether they will attend future events; then a handle sends it to psql db.

Everything works except the first iteration of the looped form does not submit correctly. Instead of continuing onto pastevents-handle.php, it doesn't post and returns a get on events.php; so I see the user's response in the url bar, but it never gets to the db. I made a test page that didn't use ajax by copy-pasting all the code and that works, so it's definitely something to do with ajax, but neither me or my professor could find out what.

I don't know how to use jquery yet, so please answer with plain javascript.

Here's events.php:

```
   <script>
    //show past events
    function showPastEvents(str) {
        document.getElementById('pastevents').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('hideoldbutton').style.display = "block";
        var xhttp;    
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("pastevents").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("pastevents").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "pastevents.php?q="+str, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    function hidePastEvents() {
        document.getElementById('pastevents').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('hideoldbutton').style.display = "none";
    }


    //show upcoming events
    function showUpcomingEvents(str) {
        document.getElementById('upcomingevents').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('hidenewbutton').style.display = "block";
        var xhttp;    
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("upcomingevents").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("upcomingevents").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "upcomingevents.php?q="+str, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    function hideUpcomingEvents() {
        document.getElementById('upcomingevents').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('hidenewbutton').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

```
        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="content"> 


            <h6>Past events</h6>

            <form name="postpastevents" action=""/>
                <div id="pastevents"></div>
                <input type="button" onClick="hidePastEvents()" id="hideoldbutton" value="Hide" style="display:none;"/>

            </form>

            <input type="button" onClick="showPastEvents()" id="showoldbutton" value="Show past"/>

            <br>
            <br>


            <!-- ####### -->
            <h6>Upcoming events</h6>

            <form name="postupcomingevents" action=""/>
                <div id="upcomingevents"></div>
                <input type="button" onClick="hideUpcomingEvents()" id="hidenewbutton" value="Hide" style="display:none;"/>

            </form>

            <input type="button" onClick="showUpcomingEvents()" id="shownewbutton" value="Show upcoming"/>
```

Here is pastevents.php (it's the same code for upcomingevents.php):

```
    <?php
        $conn = pg_connect ('dbname=xxxx') or die ('Connect failed ');

        $query = "SELECT eventname, eventdate, location, eventdesc FROM events WHERE eventdate < current_date ORDER BY eventdate;";
        $result = pg_query($query);


        while ( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result) ) {  
            $i = 0;
            echo "<tr>"; //table row
            foreach ($row as $key => $value) {  
                if ($i == 0) {
                    $eventname = $value;
                } 
                if ($i == 1) {
                    $eventdate = $value;
                }
                $eventinfo = $value;
                echo "<td>"; //1 column each loop
                    echo "$eventinfo";
                    if ($i == 1) {
                        echo date(" (l, F jS)", strtotime($eventdate));
                    }
                    echo "<br><br>";
                echo "</td>";
                $i++;
            }
            echo "<td>";//1 column while same event 
                ?>
                <div>
                    <form name="pasteventsurvey" action="pastevent-handle.php" method="post">
                        What did you think of the event?
                        <select name="pasteventopinion">
                                <option value="">(Choose one)</option>
                                <option value="good">Loved it!</option>
                                <option value="okay">Liked it</option>
                                <option value="bad">Needs improvement</option>
                                <option value="time">Time conflict</option>
                                <option value="NA">NA</option>
                        </select> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="eventname" value="<?php echo $eventname; ?>">
                        <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Submit"><input type="reset" name="erase" value="Clear">
                    </form>
                </div>
            <?php
            echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>"; //-table row
        }

        pg_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Here's pastevents-handle.php:

```
    <?php
    $conn = pg_connect ('dbname=xxxx') or die ('Connect failed ');

    pg_query_params("INSERT INTO eventsurveypast(eventname, opinion) VALUES ($1, $2)", array($name, $opinion));

    echo "email is $idkey, eventname is $name, pastopinion is $opinion"; 


    pg_close($conn);
?>
```

(I edited a bit for space, ignore anything that isn't vital)

Comment: Don't self close the opening form-tags (remove the `/` at the end).

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal to have a form inside another form.

Remove the outer form and everything should work fine, except you have another problem with the code.